# Nginx handling 10k concurrent connections

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-12.04

We are not able to handle more than 3k concurrent request in nginx (Connecton time out). We change also the ulimit to 20000. Following are my nginx.conf and sysctl.conf files:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 5000;
    use epoll;
    # multi_accept on;
}
worker_rlimit_nofile    100000;

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 600;
    send_timeout 600;
    proxy_connect_timeout       600;
    proxy_send_timeout          600;
    proxy_read_timeout          600;
    reset_timedout_connection on;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
        client_header_buffer_size 5k;
        open_file_cache max=10000 inactive=30s;
        open_file_cache_valid    60s;
        open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
        open_file_cache_errors   on;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    #access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        access_log off; 
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;



    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

systel.conf

```
# Increase size of file handles and inode cache
fs.file-max = 2097152

# Do less swapping
vm.swappiness = 10
vm.dirty_ratio = 60
vm.dirty_background_ratio = 2

### GENERAL NETWORK SECURITY OPTIONS ###

# Number of times SYNACKs for passive TCP connection.
net.ipv4.tcp_synack_retries = 2

# Allowed local port range
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 2000 65535

# Protect Against TCP Time-Wait
net.ipv4.tcp_rfc1337 = 1

# Decrease the time default value for tcp_fin_timeout connection
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 15

# Decrease the time default value for connections to keep alive
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time = 300
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 5
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 15

### TUNING NETWORK PERFORMANCE ###

# Default Socket Receive Buffer
net.core.rmem_default = 31457280

# Maximum Socket Receive Buffer
net.core.rmem_max = 12582912

# Default Socket Send Buffer
net.core.wmem_default = 31457280

# Maximum Socket Send Buffer
net.core.wmem_max = 12582912

# Increase number of incoming connections
net.core.somaxconn = 65536

# Increase number of incoming connections backlog
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 65536

# Increase the maximum amount of option memory buffers
net.core.optmem_max = 25165824

# Increase the maximum total buffer-space allocatable
# This is measured in units of pages (4096 bytes)
net.ipv4.tcp_mem = 65536 131072 262144
net.ipv4.udp_mem = 65536 131072 262144

# Increase the read-buffer space allocatable
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 8192 87380 16777216
net.ipv4.udp_rmem_min = 16384

# Increase the write-buffer-space allocatable
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 8192 65536 16777216
net.ipv4.udp_wmem_min = 16384

# Increase the tcp-time-wait buckets pool size to prevent simple DOS attacks
net.ipv4.tcp_max_tw_buckets = 1440000
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
```

We are using ubuntu OS with 4 CPU and 8 GB RAM. I hardly see any CPU and RAM usage. I am just firing nginx default page URL.

Comment: Your `net.ipv4.tcp_mem` seems low to me. It means kernel will likely start dropping packets when the TCP stack usage reaches `262144 * 4096 = 1,073 Gib` while you have 8 Gb of RAM installed. Better let the kernel auto-tune this on boot.